# Symfony2 rest api security configuration (Trying to understand)

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, symfony, oauth

I', working on a rest api with Symfony2 (FOSRestBundle, FOSOauthBundle, JMSBundle) and I do not understand (and don't find) how I'm supposed to setup my angularjs app to access my api resources. I'm a bit confused about the security part and have a lot of question.

1- I prepared the oauth client. since angular code is exposed I'm pretty sure that I can't add my secret and client id inside the code for authentication so I'm stack. H

2- I'm having (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin') error when I try to access the resources. How can I simply allow my app to access the resources (CORS! nelmio/cors-bundle?) but then I'm getting confused about the role of oauth and CORS authorization of my app.

Any help will be appreciate. 
Thanks

Comment: CORS is not a function of authentication - that's just a way to relax the same origin policy. So don't let that confuse you - CORS and OAuth are doing different, mutually exclusive things.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can expose. It's not fully authorization. It's only a client auth, not a user.
2. NelmioCorsBundle is a good choice. You need a config like this:

   ```
   nelmio_cors:
       defaults:
           allow_credentials: false
           allow_origin: []
           allow_headers: []
           allow_methods: []
           expose_headers: []
           max_age: 0
           hosts: []
       paths:
           '^/':
               allow_origin: ['*']
               allow_headers: ['origin', 'x-requested-with', 'content-type', 'authorization']
               allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
               max_age: 0
   ```

There is *allow_origin*, you should set it to **my.frontend.domain.com**. This will open your API for example for your AngularJS frontend. If you are building API as a service (open for everyone), than open to all origins "*".

CORS is not authorization. Treat it as firewall. Than you still need authorization (OAuth).